# Is "A is associated with B" equivalent to "B is associated with A?"

Tags: word-usage

Can we use equivalently "A is associated with B" and "B is associated with A"??

Comment: Please provide actual examples of what you mean. We aren't good at math here. ")

Comment: @tchrist is there any reason to think that this is a math question?

Comment: Almost never. Better avoid.

Comment: What's unclear about this?!!

Comment: Ok, folks: it is grammatically equivalent. But generally, we say: A is to B as B is to A.

Comment: @tchrist Ahem. That's perhaps too broad a statement...

Comment: Are you really using the letters "A" & "B" is your sentence - or are they substitutes for other words?

Comment: Serpico may have been associated with the NYPD, but that doesn't mean that the NYPD was "associated" with Serpico.

Answer (score 1):

In layman's terms (not invoking formal/academic logic in the answer)...
an English speaker might assume that one implies the other, especially if there's no need for clarification on what 'associated' entails.

However grammar typically (but not always) places the **subject** towards the **beginning** of the sentence, and the **object** towards the **end**. The object in a sentence being the entity that is **acted upon** by the subject.

"*James **fed the dogs***" leaves the dogs as the object being acted upon but James as the **subject**.

Where "associated" calls for more clarification, it can be too vague a term, and the inverse is NOT identical:

1. This garbage collection company is associated with the mafia
2. The mafia is associated with this garbage collection company

1 implies you are concerned with this garbage collection company in particular - maybe the existence of the mafia is a given, but you wish to discuss the garbage collection company.

2 implies you wish to discuss the mafia in particular - our discussion will revolve around the mafia and their attributes more than the company itself.

These are not hard rules but whichever one you begin with would be the one I *assume* you think is the **subject** of discussion.